# Change Android app internal name

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

The internal name of many Andoird apps is of the format **com.microsoft.skydrive**. I would like to name my app following that format, but am unsure as to how to do that *without changing the user-visible name*.

So how do I change the app's internal name without changing the visible name? (I'm using VS2015 Xamarin.Forms)

Comment: You are actually asking about "package" I think, not app visible name

Comment: @Booger Thanks! You can transform your comment into an answer. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to Package name?

For changing Package name right click module you want to change then select Refactor then click on rename.

More Refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

If you want change App name(Visible to public),

change the `android:label` field in your application code in `AndroidManifest.xml`